# What tactics did Captain Orpheus Cambarro employ to seize control of Imboca?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft

In Stuart Gordon's 2001 film *Dagon* (an adaptation of H.P. Lovecraft's novella *The Shadow Over Innsmouth*), a dramatic flashback sequence shows how the townspeople of Imboca were led astray by Captain Orpheus Cambarro and turned to the evil worship of Dagon. How could Cambarro have held sway over the townsfolk so easily and caused them to do unspeakable deeds such as desecrating the local Catholic church and murdering its priest, not to mention installing him as their leader? I am interested to know what psychological tactics Cambarro used to achieve his goal.

Comment: In the original story, IIRC, most of the townspeople were hybrids -- descended from the Deep Ones.